# How to import repo from gitlab into Phabricator via phab api?

Tags: api, gitlab, phabricator

I want to create a batch of Repository in Phabricator. These repo already created in gitlab, So i want to just export them into Phabricator via APIs. But i didn't find those APIs worked for this. i could do this manually via Phab UI, like this, while it is not efficient for batch of repository.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IjWY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `diffusion.repository.edit`?  That should be suitable for creating the repositories.  Then either use git to push the repository contents, or use diffusion.uri.edit to set all other URLs to read-only temporarily and add an "observe" URI pointing to the gitlab repository, then after everything is all synced, remove the gitlab URL and set the others back to read/write.